# シェルスクリプトでteeを使ってファイル追記する書き方について

Tags: shellscript

```
echo -e "\nexport PYENV_ROOT=$PYENV" | sudo tee -a ~/.bash_profile  >> /dev/null
```

というシェルスクリプトの書き方を見かけたのですが

```
echo "\nexport PYENV_ROOT=$PYENV" >> ~/.bash_profile
```

と何か違いがあるのでしょうか

tee -a コマンド
自分が所持してるに決まってる .bash_profile に sudo をつける意図

の２点がよくわからないのですが説明していただけるとありがたいです

.bash_profile が存在しなかった場合
.bash_profile が作成され所有者は実行ユーザではなく
root で作成されてしまうのでかえってまずい結果になりそうな気がします

単なるミスなのかこういう書き方をすることでメリットや慣習があれのか知りたいです

Comment: linux で分からないコマンドはまず `man` コマンドで調べる癖をつけることをおすすめします。

Comment: man echo は -e の説明が出てきませんし -h --help とかオプションが全部出力されてしまいます。tee は調べるまでもなくただ標準入出力をつなげるだけで -a が append というのは知ってるんですが >> と書くだけで済むのに何故 tee が必要なのかが知りたいです

Comment: `echo` に関して言えば、これはシェル(bash)の builtin function なので `man bash` で調べるか、もしくは `help echo` とします。もっとも、Ubuntu の `echo(1)` には `-e` の説明が載っていますが…

Comment: そうなのですね…　MAC環境なので出てこなくて質問してしまいました。次からは気をつけます。申し訳ありません。

Comment: MAC環境なのですね。そうでしたら BSD なので /bin/echo には `-e` オプションがありませんので、man echo に記載がないのは当然ですね。こちらこそ失礼しました。

Comment: 正確にはスクリプトが置いてあった場所は EC2 AmazonLinux2 でそれを docker 上で動かそうとしてるのでどちらも Linux です。ただ man を実行してしまったのが MAC だったので環境によって echo コマンドが違うということを知りませんでした。勉強になりました

Comment: この書き方の出所なのですが、Qiita の記事 [Spark + IPython環境をAmazon EMR上で構築し、簡単なData解析を動かして見る(第1回:環境構築編)](https://qiita.com/taka4sato/items/377a9dedb6842f056e60) でしょうか？ (検索した限りではこれ以外に見つかりませんでした)

Comment: スクリプトを描いたのは別部署の方なので出どころはわからないです。おそらく機械学習系なのでもしかしたらそれかもしれません

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### echo -e

echo コマンドは外部コマンドかシェルの内部コマンドか、また内部コマンドでもシェルの種類によって動作が違うので、`man echo` では動作の詳細がわからない事が有ります。
今回の場合はおそらく bash の内部コマンドの echo の動作だと思うので、`man bash` で調べる必要が有ります。

bash のマニュアルでの echo の説明には以下のように書かれています。

> If the -e option is  given,  interpretation  of  the  following backslash-escaped characters is enabled.
>   ～略～
>                 \n     new line

つまり `-e` を付けると `\n` が改行に変換されて出力されるという事です。逆に `-e` を付けないと '\n' がそのまま出力されます。

### tee -a

`tee -a` は標準入力から読んだ内容をファイルに追加すると同時に標準出力にも出力するコマンドですが、標準出力は /dev/null にリダイレクトして捨てているので、単純にファイルに追記するコマンドとして利用しています。
これだけだと `>>` で追記するのと違いが判りづらいですが、今回の場合は `sudo` と組み合わせている事に意味があります。

`echo -e "hoge" | sudo tee -a ~/.profile >> /dev/null` の場合は `tee` がroot権限で起動されてファイルに追記します。
一方 `sudo echo "hoge" >> ~/.profile` の場合は、echo コマンドがroot権限で起動されますが、その出力をリダイレクトでファイルに書き込む(出力先を~/.profileにする)のはシェルが行う為、`sudo`による権限昇格の影響を受けません。

Comment: 丁寧にありがとうございます。パイプの前後(出力と書き込み)で権限を分けるために tee を使っているということなのですね。自分の bash_profile への追記に sudo をする理由は謎ですが root 以外で変更できないようにするのが意図だったのかもしれないですね

Answer (score 2):

## Solaris 10のshの場合

`tee -a ファイル`と`>>ファイル`は次の点で結果が変わることがあります。

- `tee -a`はファイルを`O_APPEND`で`open`して`write`する。
- `>>ファイル`はファイルの末尾に`lseek`して`write`する。

あるプロセスが`>>ファイル`を実行しているとき、`lseek`と`write`の間で、別のプロセスが割り込んで同じファイルに対して`>>ファイル`を実行すると、２つのプロセスの`write`結果が混ざってしまうことがあります。

shに依存する振る舞いかもしれませんが、`Solaris 10`のshではそうでした。
※　shスクリプトでログ出力していたときに、ログファイルが乱れていたので、その原因を調べた結果です。

Solaris10の環境が残っていたので`/bin/sh`の振る舞いを`truss`で確認しました。ファイルの末尾にシークしています。

[image: trussの結果]

なお、`/bin/bash`では`O_APPEND`で`open`していました。

---

## bashでの結果

centosでもbashの振る舞いを確認してみました。
結果は`Bourne Shell`のときと違っており、リダイレクト先のファイルを`O_APPEND`で`open`していました。

**スクリプト**

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "AAA" >> ./log
```

**straceの結果**

```
openat(AT_FDCWD, "./log", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_APPEND, 0666) = 3
fcntl(1, F_GETFD)                       = 0
fcntl(1, F_DUPFD, 10)                   = 10
fcntl(1, F_GETFD)                       = 0
fcntl(10, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)          = 0
dup2(3, 1)                              = 1
close(3)                                = 0
fstat(1, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=8, ...}) = 0
write(1, "AAA\n", 4)                    = 4
```

この結果は、`GNU bash, バージョン 4.4.20`のものです。

**確認したbashのバージョン**

`GNU bash, バージョン 4.4.20(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`

Solaris10で確認したときのバージョンは以下です。
`GNU bash, バージョン 3.2.51(1)-release (i386-pc-solaris2.10)`